# Can't take a proper screenshot with shutter

Tags: fedora, wayland, screenshot, shutter

I'm running Fedora 25 and I need to take a few particular screen captures so I've read that shutter is a great tool for that. Sadly I am unable to use it for some reason. Whenever I try to take a screenshot this is the result:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora 25 is using Wayland and a lot of applications are not prepared for that (especially the ones that do not expect any security or limitation when accessing shared resources such as the whole screen). This is certainly a bug in shutter and it is already filled as a bugs [#1299293](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1299293), [#1363845](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1363845), [#1399331](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1399331).

If you want to take screenshots, you will either have to [use old X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935697/fedora-android-studio-is-not-running/40951490#40951490), or use different tool on Wayland, until it gets fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I also used shutter a lot to make and easily rename screengrabs and was sad to see it broken by Wayland in Fedora 27.

gnome-screenshot is a pretty useful utility to make screengrabs in Fedora-wayland. It can be quite easily used to create a workaround for Shutter in Wayland as follows:

1) Create scripts shut.sh and grabname.sh as appended.

2) make them executable (chmod +x ) and save them in an existing command path so they can be called from the command line eg. in /usr/bin . I tend to save my custom scripts in /usr/local/bin but this has to be added to default path using visudo.

3) Now when you run shut.sh a cursor will appear. Use it to draw a rectangle and Terminal will pop up asking you for a name for your new file (grabname.sh). You can use spaces in the filename. It will then ask you if you want to prefix file with yyyymmdd (y). Hit return or anything else to skip prefix.

4) Your renamed file is saved in /my/temp/location

5) Save this as shut.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh

# START shut.sh

# This script calls gnome-screen shot in Wayland to take a rectangular     screenshot
# resulting png is saved to /my/temp/location
# script then calls a second script (grabname.sh) which asks you for a filename to give the grab with the option to prefix current date if you want
# make sure both scripts are in a relevant executable path for your kernel eg. /usr/bin etc.
# You can allocate shut.sh to a hot key in settings and make screengrabs via a hotkey.

gnome-screenshot -a -f /my/temp/location/grabcache.png

gnome-terminal -e "bash grabname.sh"

# END shut.sh
```

grabname.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# START grabname.sh

# Previous script shut.sh calls gnome-screen shot in Wayland to take a rectangular screenshot
# resulting png is saved to /my/temp/location
# This script (grabname.sh) asks you for a filename to give the grab with the option to prefix current date if you want
#  * spaces are allowed in filenames *
# make sure both scripts are in a relevant executable path for your kernel eg. /usr/bin etc.

# set -x

IFS=$'\n'

read -p "Name for grab? " grab

while true; do

    read -p "Append date yyyymmdd (y or anything else for no) ?" yn

    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) ap=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M_)
        break;;

    * ) echo -e "\n\e[0;34mNot prefixing date...\e[0m\n"; ap="";break;;
    esac
done

echo $ap$grab

cp /my/temp/location/grabcache.png /my/temp/location/"$ap$grab".png

nautilus /my/temp/location

# END grabname.sh
```